# Insert a new value in a column and this new value should get added for other column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, sql-insert

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
id   field_name
111     A
111     B
111     C
189     A
189     B
189     C
```

I wanted to add a new field_name "D" to all my id's. My table will have 6000+ distinct ids. Regular insert does not work.

Need an output like below:

```
id   field_name
111     A
111     B
111     C
111     D
189     A
189     B
189     C
189     D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert ... select` like so:

```
insert into mytable(id, field_name)
select distinct id, 'D' from mytable
```

This creates one row per `id`, with a constant value of `'D'` as `field_name`.

If you want to avoid tuples that already exist, if any:

```
insert into mytable(id, field_name)
select distinct id, 'D' from mytable
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.field_name = 'D')
```

Or, for the same purpose, you can have a unique index or constraint on the tuple of values, and use `on conflict`.

```
create unique index myidx on mytable(id, field_name);

insert into mytable(id, field_name)
select distinct id, 'D' from mytable
on conflict (id, fieldname) do nothing;
```

Comment: Need to query in postgres. I have a query which will fetch 3036 rows. I wanted to fetch from 2400 th row to 3036 row. Can i give this in limit in postgres ? or else any other idea ?